# Statsmodels: Get the error correlation matrix from VARMAX.fit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

I would like to be able to use the values of the error correlation matrix. I know I can get it through `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEResults.summary()`:

```
model = sm.tsa.VARMAX(endog=df, order=(2, 0))
result = model.fit()
results_summary = result.summary()
errorCor = results_summary.tables[4]
```

`errorCor` is now a `SimpleTable`, but I would like to convert it to a `list` or `pd.DataFrame`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it using a trial and error method and the `dir()` method. You can just use `model.fit().params` to obtain the info that I needed.